# JQuery - Abrem todas as abas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, front-end

Criei uma div que irá expandir.
Mas quando clico em expandir, todas as divs abrem ao invés de abrir apenas a que quero expandir.
Tem alguma forma de abrir apenas a div que cliquei?

Observação: Será conectado ao banco de dados e novas divs serão criadas com o tempo, então ID não está em cogitação.

Meu código:

Html:

```html
<div class="titulo">Título</div>
   <div class="open"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down></i></div>
   <div class="open"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up></i></div>
<div class="corpo"></div>
```

Css:

```css
i.fa-chevron-up{display: none}
.corpo{display: none}
```

Jquery:

```
$("i.fa-chevron-down").click(function(){
   $(".corpo").slideDown(500);
   $("i.fa-chevron-down").hide(0);
   $("i.fa-chevron-up").show(0);
});

$(".fa-chevron-up").click(function(){
   $(".corpo").slideUp(500);
   $("i.fa-chevron-down").show(0);
   $("i.fa-chevron-up").hide(0);     
});
```

Comment: Emanoel, com este css nada é apresentado na tela com exceção do título. Verifica se é isto mesmo.

Comment: Cara, eu não posso te ajudar com esse código, faz um exemplo funcional aqui: https://jsbin.com/

Answer (score 0):

Não testei, mas acredito que funcione:

```
<div class="titulo">Título</div>
   <div class="open"><i class="fas">a</i></div>
   <div class="open"><i class="fas">v</i></div>
<div class="corpo"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".fas").on("click",function(){
    $(".fas").hide();
    $(this).show()
});
</script>
```

Use o script após o html para que o jquery consiga captar qual objeto esta sendo clicado para poder capturar o valor de `this`

Comment: Se preferir, para dar um efeito mais interessante, troque hide() por slideUp() e show() por slideDown();